# prevent reload before submitting form with laravel 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been trying to prevent a page to reload when submitting a form with laravel4.

I don't want the page to reload everytime there is a problem when submitting the form.
here is the js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').on('submit',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var that = $(this);

        var url = that.attr('action');

        var action = that.attr('method');

        $.post(url,action,that.serializeArray())
        .done(function (data,text,jqhr) {

                console.log('data');
            })
        .fail(function(jqxhr){
            alert(jqxhr.responseText)
        })

        .always(function () {
            that.find('button').text('Send Message');
        })
    });

});
//end of document ready function
```

ContactController.php:

```
    <?php
class ContactController extends BaseController{



       public function getIndex (){

        return View::make('Contact.contact');
        }

        public function postContact(){

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'name'      =>'required|min:2',
            'email'     =>'required|email',
            'sujet'     =>'required',
            'telephone' =>'required|phone:US,CA',
            'message'   =>'required'
        ));

            if($validator->passes()){

                $contact = new Contact();

                $contact -> nom         = Input::get('name');
                $contact -> email       = Input::get('email');
                $contact -> sujet       = Input::get('sujet');
                $contact -> telephone   = Input::get('telephone');
                $contact -> message     = Input::get('message');

                if(Request::ajax){

                    $contact->save();
                    return Redirect::route('contact')
                        ->with('success','Votre message a ete envoyee, on vous contactera!');
                }

                else{
                    return View::make('Contact.contact');
                }

            }else{

                return Redirect::route('contact')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            }

        }
    }
```

route:

```
Route::group(array('before'=> 'csfr'),function(){

        Route::post('Contact/send-message', array(

            'as' => 'postContact',

            'uses' => 'ContactController@postContact'
        ));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the onSubmit event handler to a onClick handler on the submit button. The onSubmit event is fired when the data is posted to the server and is thus too late to prevent a reload.

```
 $('#submit_button').on('click',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var that = $('#contact_form');

        var url = that.attr('action');

        var action = that.attr('method');

        $.post(url,action,that.serializeArray())
        .done(function (data,text,jqhr) {

                console.log('data');
            })
        .fail(function(jqxhr){
            alert(jqxhr.responseText)
        })

        .always(function () {
            that.find('button').text('Send Message');
        })
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, i just made the change. But i still have a problem the data object data are not sent to the controller... when i submit, the data dont get submitted... @joe_archer

Comment: This is a different issue. I would just serialise the form data as such $("#contact_form").serialize(); before posting.

Comment: $.post(url,action,that.serializeArray()) i did serialize()the form.. maybe that'sthe issue i'm facing then, i can't pass the json   to the controller to process the submitting form. @joe_archer

Comment: As your original question is answered, please mark this as such. If you're having other issues, please post another question or expand this one to include your other problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Initial Issue

Everything looks fine, except for the call to `$.post`. The form data is passed in as the second parameter, not the third. The signature for the `$.post` method is:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

So, you should be fine if you change your call to:

```
$.post(url, that.serializeArray())
```

#### Form Action

If you would like to use the action defined on the form, you would need to switch to using the `$.ajax` method. The `$.get` and `$.post` methods are shortcuts for those actions, so the action cannot be changed.  With `$.ajax`, you have full control. In that case, you'd be looking at something like:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    type: action,
    data: that.serializeArray()
}).done(function (data,text,jqhr) {
    console.log('data');
}).fail(function(jqxhr){
    alert(jqxhr.responseText)
}).always(function () {
    that.find('button').text('Send Message');
});
```

#### Notes

- The form submit event should work fine. It is a cancelable event.
- Both `$.serialize` and `$.serializeArray` should work.

Comment: Thanks @patricus. I made those changes but i still can't post the data in the database. maybe i'm doing something wrong with the contrller.

Comment: Have you verified you're getting into the Controller? How are you determining if you received any input?  Also, I don't know if this was just a typo in your post, but `Request::ajax` should be a method call: `Request::ajax()`.

Comment: @GaetanSobze what was the final issue?

Comment: in the controller i didnt return the data in a json format. and in my app.js file, i just console.log the data but didnt actually do anything with the data. I added two <div> section in the view.blade file with error and success_message classes. I hope you get me @patricus